# Fatal error: Call to undefined method cant call my SP properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cant call my SP properly in CI can someone help me?

This is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Welcome::navi_model() in /home/development/public_html/rmt/application/controllers/welcome.php on line 252

Here is my sample code:

**Controller**

```
    function upload_gen048()
{

$data['uploadData']=$this->input->post('upload');

            $this->load->model('navi_model');
            $query = $this->navi_model($data); 
            $data = array('msg' => "Upload success!");
            $data['main_content'] = 'gen048';
            $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
            $data['uploadData'] = $this->upload->data();
```

**Model**

```
function upload_gen048($data)
{

$qString = '[gen048upload] '; //STORED PROCEDURE
    $qString .= "'" 
             . $data['filedate'] . "','";
             . $data['accdate'] . "','";

        echo $qString;

        $this->db->query('set ansi_padding on
                        set ARITHABORT on
                        set CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL on
                        set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on
                        set ANSI_NULLS on
                        set ANSI_WARNINGS on
                        set numeric_roundabort off');

        $query = $this->db->query($qString);

    return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : NULL;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to pass $data to constructor method of class??

Comment: navi_model.php. I am sorry but how will I know the version of my CI?

Comment: Well you need to add method name while calling your model from controller!!

Comment: Yes sir, that is what im thinking right now, I am sorry but I am still learning so I need a few help. I hope you understand :D

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to pass data to your model's constructor method then you should write.

```
 $params = array('param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2');

 $this->load->library('navi_model', $params);
```

Else

you need to specify method name compulsory after model class name like:-

```
$this->navi_model->method_name($params);
```

Answer (score 2):

To call model function form controller we use

```
 $query = $this->MODEL_NAME->METHOD_NAME(PARAMETER);
```

You need to add method name while calling your model from controller

Change

```
$query = $this->navi_model($data);
```

To

```
$query = $this->navi_model->upload_gen048($data); // add method name here
```

Read https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

## Controller

```
function upload_gen048()
{

$data['uploadData']=$this->input->post('upload');

            $this->load->model('navi_model');
            $query = $this->navi_model->function_name($data); //here is your mistake
            $data = array('msg' => "Upload success!");
            $data['main_content'] = 'gen048';
            $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
            $data['uploadData'] = $this->upload->data();
}
```

Try it and let me know is it working or not

You can vist [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html) for more detail aboit CI how to call function and that all

[how-to-call-model-from-controller-in-codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754464/how-to-call-model-from-controller-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @VinceOsana replace `function_name` with `upload_gen048`

Comment: use `$query = $this->navi_model->upload_gen048($data); 
`

Comment: I am really sorry!! stupid me I am doing a lot of homework, I forgot to read carefully. thanks for this~!